# Notepad++ - cannot launch Firefox

Tags: 14.04, wine

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and Notepad++ 6.6.4 (through WINE)

Under the 'Run' tab, I clicked on "Launch in Firefox" , but nothing happened

- I uninstalled Notepad++ and WINE, then shutdown.
- I re-installed Notepad++ and WINE and still have the same problem.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: If I may ask, why do you want Notepad++?  `gedit` which comes with Ubuntu is a native program in Ubuntu that does pretty much everything that Notepad++ does.

Answer (score 8):

Notepad++ doesn't work out of the box via Wine with the installed Firefox software.

You will need to install Firefox under Wine to make it work, using the Windows installer for Firefox.  Notepad++ should then work with Firefox under Wine.

---

An alternative to Notepad++ is the already-installed `gedit` software.  It does most of the same functions as Notepad++ in terms of syntax highlighting and such, and comes included with Ubuntu.

Comment: Use also geany: `sudo apt-get install geany`

Comment: I was just trying out different editors. I will stick with gedit.

Comment: @user288901 OK.  That's fine, you can do that.  (As an FYI, you should probably close this question if it answers what you're asking, and you can do that by selecting this answer as the answer that helped, if it is indeed the answer that helped.)

Answer (score 0):

Use an  alternative to Notepad++, Notepadqq for example and it can be installed by entering the following commands in a terminal session:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install notepadqq
```

Source can be found [here](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/wp/download/).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem after some update. when I run the notepad++ on the terminal, I noticed that there are some warning and instruction. I can run the notepad++ when I applied the instructions. You could find the instructions below.

You need to connect this snap to the wine-platform snap.
snap disconnect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug

```
snap install wine-platform

snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug wine-platform:wine-base-stable
```

Remove deprecated wine-platform-i386 snap.

```
snap remove wine-platform-i386
```

good luck.